# How to calculate working days for each month dynamically ?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am developing attendance system by using Php.

I have to calculate total office working days for each month except holidays.

If someone take leave means that the person working day should be minus 1 from the office working day.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: that totally depends on your office if it is granting holidays on all standard occasions.

Comment: I'm not implement code for this yet. Because I don't have any idea how to integrate it. That's only I put in this site..

Comment: read the stack overflow [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and read [what have you tried)](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try it, I think it will help you.

```
var get_working_days  = function(year, month_number){
  var start_dt = new Date(year, month_number, 1);
  var end_dt = null;
  var count_sunday = 0;

  /* these are moonth number on based of index like 0 for jan, 1 for feb etc*/
  var month_31 = [0,2,4,6,7,9,11];
  var month_30 = [3,5,8,10];
  var month_feb = [1];

  if(month_31.indexOf(month_number) >= 0){
    end_dt = new Date(year, month_number, 31);
  }else if(month_30.indexOf(month_number) >= 0){
    end_dt = new Date(year, month_number, 30);
  }else if(month_feb.indexOf(month_number) >= 0){
    if(year%4 == 0){
      end_dt = new Date(year, month_number, 29);
    }else{
      end_dt = new Date(year, month_number, 28);
    }
  }
  var number_of_days = end_dt.getDate();
  while(number_of_days >= 7){
    count_sunday += 1;
    number_of_days = number_of_days - 7;
  }
  if(number_of_days > 0){
    if(start_dt.getDay()+number_of_days >= 7){
      count_sunday += 1;    
    }
  }
  var working_days = end_dt.getDate() - count_sunday;
  return working_days;
}

var dt = new Date();
var year = dt.getFullYear();
var month_lst = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec' ]
var month = dt.getMonth()+1; /*pass number 1 ,2 3 ... for month on the based of indes   like 0 for january*/
for(var count = 0 ; count < month_lst.length; count++){
  var working_days = get_working_days(year, count)
  console.log(" Working days of "+month_lst[count] +" " + year +" are : "+ working_days);
}
```

please have a look on image for more understanding.

[image]